# retrofit, send multipart body with image

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

so I have a solution but its not perfect and I am curious if retrofit provides a way to turn a model into a MultiPartBody. Since I need to send a flattened model and a image.

Currently I am turning the model into a Map. Then recursively going through it and adding the appropriate fields to the MultiPartBody via the builder and when its a list parsing through that and adding those items with the appropriate form notation.

Comment: So, what's the question/problem? And where's your [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just modifying the server to accept the model as a RequestPart so the whole thing can just be a @Part.